# When trying to populate a DropDownList in an UpdatePanel, I get a 404 error(> Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: )

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a dropDownList with radio buttons. The radio buttons are there for sorting the DropDownList(by name, by id etc). The DropDownList is being populated by the Database via stored procedure. It is surrounded by an update panel.

```
    <div id="casefiles">
    <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div id="rbfileByHolder" runat="server">
                    <label>Sort By</label>
                    <span><asp:RadioButton class="aspRBs" GroupName="rbfileByNameOrID" ID="rbMyFiles" Text="My Files" Checked="true"
                        runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="rbMyFiles_CheckedChanged" /></span>
                    <span><asp:RadioButton class="aspRBs" GroupName="rbfileByNameOrID" id="rbByFileID"
                        Text="By File ID"  runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
                        oncheckedchanged="rbByFileID_CheckedChanged" /></span>
                    <span><asp:RadioButton class="aspRBs" GroupName="rbfileByNameOrID" id="rbByFileName"
                        Text="By File Name" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
                        oncheckedchanged="rbByFileName_CheckedChanged" /></span>            

                </div><br />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <label>Select New CaseFile</label>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlCaseFiles" DataSourceID="dsMyCaseFiles" DataTextField="Display" DataValueField="FileID" OnPreRender="ddl_PreRender" Width="524px" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlCaseFiles" ToolTip="Casefile Required" InitialValue="-1" Text="*" Display="Dynamic" />
                <ajaxToolkit:ListSearchExtender ID="ddlExtCaseFiles" runat="server" PromptCssClass="ListSearchExtenderPrompt" TargetControlID="ddlCaseFiles" BehaviorID="ddlExtCaseFiles" Enabled="True"/>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rbByFileName" EventName="CheckedChanged" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rbByFileID" EventName="CheckedChanged" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rbMyFiles" EventName="CheckedChanged" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
```

Here is my javascript function for showing the controls in a popup:

```
//create popup with dropdownLists then call moveCaseFile
    function getCaseFiles(canCopyTo) {
        //create Popup with content from div
        $('#casefiles').dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            height: 'auto',
            width: 'auto',
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Ok": function () {
                    debugger;
                    alert("test");
                    var t = $("#casefiles");
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    $("#viewExpensesGrid").flexReload();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

And here is the relevant code behind(radio button sorting and assigning default values for the dropdownlist):

```
protected void rbByFileName_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ddlCaseFiles.DataSourceID = "dsCaseFilesReverse";
    ddlCaseFiles.DataTextField = "Display";
    ddlCaseFiles.DataValueField = "FileID";
}

protected void rbByFileID_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ddlCaseFiles.DataSourceID = "dsCaseFiles";
    ddlCaseFiles.DataTextField = "Display";
    ddlCaseFiles.DataValueField = "FileID";
}

protected void rbMyFiles_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ddlCaseFiles.DataSourceID = "dsMyCaseFiles";
    ddlCaseFiles.DataTextField = "Display";
    ddlCaseFiles.DataValueField = "FileID";
}
protected void ddl_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
    try
    {
        if (ddl.Items[0].Value != "-1")
            ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "-1"));
    }
    catch
    {
        ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "-1"));
    }
}
```

Ok. Time to explain more.

A popup is suppose to appear and look like this:
![enter image description here][1]

If you click on myFiles, it sorts the drop down list showing all the files you have (via stored procedure). So for every radio button, it gets sorted differently with different information(via stored procedure). But my problem is that when I select a radio button(and it has to execute the stored proc), I get this error:

Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 404

What I think is messing it up is the UpdatePanel/AutoPostback. Instead of just updating the dropdownlist, it tries to refresh the page as well but to another link or something. Please help  before kittens get drop kicked

This is the error I get from the chrome debugger:

> Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 404

All these errors happend when I added the AutoPostback="true".

Comment: Is this the jQuery UI dialog?

Comment: yes, it is exactly that.

Comment: If I recall, the jQueryUI dialog gets appended to the `body`. Which puts it *outside* the one and only ASP.Net form, which causes all sorts of trouble with web forms in general. I would suggest inspecting the DOM while the dialog is open to confirm where it has been relocated.

Comment: It seems to be in the body when I inspect it.

Comment: It's not clear to me from your question if you are submitting the form from inside the dialog. If so, that's probably the issue.

Comment: how would I do that? I've tried
open: function(type, data) {
                        $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
                    }

Comment: It seems to have put it in the form now and inside the body tag. However it doesn't even do a postback now, it just goes straight to "404 an error occured" and the code behind doesn't even run

Comment: Interesting...at least you know that the dialog's location is impacting the behavior. What URL does it try to go to? Does everything work correctly if you remove the dialog (and just show the panel inline)?